# SVG Union of Shapes using javascript or d3 or inkscape script like Inkscape GUI does

Tags: javascript, svg, union, diagram

I am doing a simple website where I put some graphics. Now I do each diagram using Inkscape. I use Inkscape to make UNION operations between the shapes. Then I save the new diagram, do another union, save, and so on. I need repeat this about 150 times :(

I would like to know if I could do it using javascript or D3 library. Or at least a way that makes Inkscape do it automatically.

In the perfect case, there would be a function:

```
union(shapeA,shapeB): replace ShapeA and ShapeB by ShapeAunionB
```

Could you give me any tips about this problem? Any help?

Comment: It's possible to script inkscape to do that. See http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine.html for how to get started.

Comment: Thank you Erik! :) I have done a script in Python and it calls Inkscape command line, like your suggested website explains.


    `command = "inkscape -f file.svg --verb=EditDeselect --select=shapeA --select=shapeB --verb=SelectionUnion --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose"
    os.system(command)`

Comment: It would be nice if you posted your solution as an answer I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a script in Python and it calls Inkscape command line, like  suggested website by  Erik Dahlström  explains.

```
command = "inkscape -f file.svg --verb=EditDeselect --select=shapeA --select=shapeB --verb=SelectionUnion --verb=FileSave --verb=FileClose" os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an opensource library: [Javascript Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/)

The Javascript Clipper library performs clipping and offsetting for both lines and polygons. All four boolean clipping operations are supported - intersection, union, difference and exclusive-or. Polygons can be of any shape including self-intersecting polygons.

features demo: http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.2/main_demo.html

[image]